# Alternative solution to WINAPI CreateFile()

Tags: windows

I am developing program on window's using msys and mingw. I want to have similar function as provided by WINAPI CreateFile(). Is there any solution for this?

Regards,
Dhaval

Comment: Why wouldn't you use CreateFile?

Comment: To add to Joe's question - the only way to open a file on Windows is CreateFile - whatever you use is going to use that underneath, so if you're already using CreateFile why would you want to change.

Comment: You might want to use something in the standard library for portability, but as @Joe and @Stewart say it will end up calling `CreateFile`. If you're having problems calling it, you probably haven't #include-d the right Windows headers.

Comment: @joe, @Stewart, @ pdbartlett: Thank you for your inputs and sorry to be less descriptive. In my program I am facing a issue of file locking, as the same file is being used by two processes. If I use simple fopen, I face this issue. To fix it I found that, if I use CreateFile() with share mode set to "FILE_SHARE_DELETE" I can fix it . fopen do not provide this granularity of file creation and so I am planning to use some alternative of CreateFile() my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX api for opening files is [fopen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(VS.80).aspx) - or documented @ [OpenGroup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html).

Comment: Can I open file with sharing mode similar to "FILE_SHARE_DELETE" defined for CreateFile()? which i guess is related to ACL implemented in NTFS file system.

Comment: Looking at the documentation it doesn't look like fopen has any delete-on-close functionality. You will need to use CreateFile directly to access that.

Comment: How to use it directly in mingw environment?

Comment: The mingw environment is meant to setup a windows sdk build environment: i.e. little more than a `#include <windows.h>` is necessary - then just call the windows APIs you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will try to make it work as per your suggestion.